# Configure Cargo so that it puts the result in `target/<default target>/<mode>` when there is no explicit `--target` argument?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

On Linux, if I build my project with `cargo build`, the result will be placed in `target/debug`. If I instead build it with `cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, the result is put in `target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug`, even though the result is the same.

It's inconvenient to supply the `--target` argument when I run commands manually. Setting `build.target` in `.cargo/config.toml` isn't very convenient either as I'd have to make sure to always do that. Our build scripts on the other hand need an explicit `--target`, because those scripts may run on different systems. For example, we want to make Windows builds on a Linux machine or vice versa.

If I mix manual commands (where I don't want to manually type out `--target`) and scripts (that use `--target` to make sure they build for the correct platform), Cargo will spend a lot of time rebuilding the same thing in two different directories.

So, that's why I wonder if it is possible to configure Cargo so that it puts the result in `target/<target>/<mode>` even when there is no explicit `--target` argument.

Comment: *"Cargo will spend a lot of time rebuilding the same thing in two different directories"* - are you running the CI scripts on your local machine? Why would you build the `target/<target>/<mode>` version on your local machine in the first place? (Trying to understand your problem; I haven't heard of such a config option yet, sadly, so maybe it isn't' necessary in the first place)

Comment: There is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098035/how-to-get-default-cargo-output-directory-to-match-target-architecture but which is unanswered

Comment: If setting `build.target` in `.cargo/config.toml` makes it use the `/target/<triple>/` directory, isn't that satisfactory? It doesn't sound that inconvenient if you only have to do it once per system. If you do that and want to cross-compile, you'd just use `--target` explicitly, no?

Comment: @Finomnis: Yes, we use the same scripts as the CI system locally, but there are things that are better done with a manual command-line. So we mix them.